# Umbraco 7 navigation menu link is not working

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to Umbraco. Currently, I am facing an odd problem, which is some navigation link in the menu bar does not working properly.

For example, in my navigation link, I use relative link:

```
<a href="/target"></a>
```

When I click that link on the web page, it redirect to error page, says cannot find the template. **However**, if I jump to Umbraco Admin page, and click **link to document: /target**, then it works!

I suspect when I trying to access **/target** from the webpage, it cannot find the document pointing to.

Could someone tell me some possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to republish the node? Also ensure that a template has actually been set on the content node.